# SQL statement works separately, but together it won't

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to fetch user

```
function getItemName($dbh, $userId) {
    $itemId = getItemId($dbh, $userId); // the getItemId() function works
    echo "item id is: " . $itemId ; // because I can see the correct result if I echo it
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM items WHERE id = :item_id";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(':item_id', $itemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetch();
    return $result['name'];
}
```

And I get `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool` on the `return $result['name'];` line.
The field `name` exists on the `items` table so that's not the issue.

Also, when I try to further test it, I change the `$sql` statement to `SELECT * FROM items` and then when I do `echo $stm->rowCount()` it finds the correct number of rows (With the original SQL statement row count is 0)

Can't find out what's causing this

Comment: What's your table structure? What's the code for `getItemID()`? Are you 100% sure that the value returned as `$itemId` is a valid value in the database? The _presumably_ `(bool) FALSE` response indicates that the query completed with no results...

Comment: try add `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` inside your fetch. like this: `$result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Please show us the way you connect to the database

Comment: That says that the `$result` variable is a bool (FALSE most likely) So for some reason the query failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions:

- Make sure to convert $itemId to integer using intval();
- Just before returning the function result validate that the query returned results.

```php
$result = $stm->fetch();
if(!$result){
 return null;
}
return $result['name'];
```

- Finally, the more obvious, make sure the itemId you are looking for exists in the DB.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you. I deleted a few rows from one of the tables, so it existed in one table but not on the other that's why it returned results in one function but not on the other. I will also add the `if (!$result)` to fix it in case there are no results